# php email edit interface and save method

Tags: php, html, mysql, email, editor

I've created a simple information system which, among other thins, sends automatic html emails.
The body of this emails is defined by me within the php code, where it is saved, and the automatic routine is done by a cron job.
The problem is that, every time I want to change anything to these standard emails, I have to edit a .php file, since I am the developer and the only one capable of doing it. So, what I want now is to create a simple interface on the front-office of the IS so that the administrators can view and edit themselves these emails.
How can I do this? What is the best save method for the body of this emails (mysql, html file, ...) ? Is there any html editor that I could use in my website?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
MH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a database set up, that would be a good way to do it. For an editor, I have used TinyMCE in the past and it has worked out well. 
http://www.tinymce.com/

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably be best off saving the data in a database (possibly MySQL), and if you can, build something to edit the content, or use something such as CKEditor or TinyMCE to modify the content.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to store the body on the Database using for example MySQL and then updating it with a form + php.

You can use as Shamil say, some rich text editors such as [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) which will deal with the HTML code to generate the rich text body.